# Authentication with Azure Active Directory in Multiple Regions issue

Tags: azure, windows-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am using windows azure directory authentication for credential for my site
I've create active directory in southeast-Asia subscriptions, in India sites credentials working fine with same directory but not working with north Europe region

[image]

Comment: This error says you dont have valid signup token in "IssuingAutority" or Token table. mostly signup problem.

Comment: but in india working fine with all environment, in denmark(europe) having this issue. strange!!!